# birthday code need ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, date

i have the next code and i need to do "selected" on the day now.

ex: today is 18/04/2014 so:

```
day=18
month=04
year=14
```

if not understand:

```
<select name="day" id="day">
<option value="na">day</option>
<option value="01">1</option>
<option value="02">2</option>
<option value="03">3</option>
<option value="04">4</option>
<option value="05">5</option>
<option value="06">6</option>
<option value="07">7</option>
<option value="08" selected>8</option>
<option value="09">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
</select>
```

and month and year....

**its the full code:**

```
<select name="day" id="day">
<option value="na">day</option>
<option value="01">1</option>
<option value="02">2</option>
<option value="03">3</option>
<option value="04">4</option>
<option value="05">5</option>
<option value="06">6</option>
<option value="07">7</option>
<option value="08">8</option>
<option value="09">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>/
<select name="month" id="month">
<option value="na">month</option>
<option value="01">January</option>
<option value="02">February</option>
<option value="03">March</option>
<option value="04">April</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
<option value="06">June</option>
<option value="07">July</option>
<option value="08">August</option>
<option value="09">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>/
<select name="year" id="year">
<option value="na">year</option>
<option value="14">2014</option>
</select>
```

its simple but i need help ...

if you can i Would rather ajax more.

Answer (score 0):

What does AJAX have to do with this?

```
document.getElementById('day').selectedIndex = day;
document.getElementById('month').selectedIndex = month;
document.getElementById('year').selectedIndex = year-2013;
// "year-2013" will need adjusting if you have more than just the current year
// if they are in increasing order, replace 2013 with "lowest year -1"
// otherwise, do "highest year +1" - year
```